# pod memory usage go high suddenly for some time and go down

Tags: kubernetes

container_memory_working_set_bytes metric value is very high sometimes
but container_memory_rss value is low

Checked that the application in pod container usage is low.

Comment: give some details

Comment: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2582

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@eng.mohamed.m.saeed/memory-working-set-vs-memory-rss-in-kubernetes-which-one-you-should-monitor-8ef77bf0acee) `container_memory_working_set_bytes` might be higher than `container_memory_rss` because as written [in cAdvisor code](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/50b23f4ed9bc53cf068316b67bee04c4145f1e73/info/v1/container.go#L391) it is:

> The amount of working set memory, this includes recently accessed
> memory, [dirty memory](https://superuser.com/a/1317544/1126439), and kernel memory. Working set is <=
> "usage".
> Units: Bytes.

It is [calculated as](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/90f391fddf71801f76f408d8ed191ddc006df323/container/libcontainer/handler.go#L862):

```
container_memory_usage_bytes == memory usage - inactive file memory
```

When [`container_memory_rss`](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/50b23f4ed9bc53cf068316b67bee04c4145f1e73/info/v1/container.go#L379) is:

> The amount of anonymous and swap cache memory (includes
> transparent hugepages).
> Units: Bytes.

and it is the value of `total_rss` from `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat` file.

Comment: That comment is wrong: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/90f391fddf71801f76f408d8ed191ddc006df323/container/libcontainer/handler.go#L862 it's calculated as "memory usage - inactive file memory"

Comment: @zerkms thanks for pointing out my mistake, I've edited my answer